# Is it possible to disable brower refresh capabilities with JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

The reason I ask such an odd question is that I currently am creating computer based test environment, and obviously in the test I have a live countdown timer. Unfortunately on refreshing the page the timer is reset :(.

Obviously I will be looking to involve some method of storing the start time server side so that it always starts the countdown from this. However in a test situation I want the user to be locked in essentially, so I want to know if I can disable the browser navigationg buttons like back and refresh.

Comment: There are plenty of resources for that here already: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=disable+refresh

Comment: _'the timer is reset.'_ Who cares? Consider it a 'known issue' in testing.

Comment: @Mr.Disappointment, the the examinee would have infinite time to complete the test. Keep your pointless comments to yourself.

Comment: I think you would have gotten better answers by asking how to "lock the timer/user in" (the thing you're actually trying to do) than explicitly asking how to disable the refresh button.

Comment: @buymypies: Then they aren't testers if they're just exploiting a known issue. And, my 'pointless' comments are only evoked by such an irrational request - if you want to restrict application behaviour, write an application. Plus, you didn't say 'please keep...'

Comment: @Mr. Disappointment: You're thinking software tester, he's talking about a person taking a quiz/exam.

Comment: @Madmartigan: I suppose, but the request should spawn advice against trying to control users' systems. regardless.

Answer (score 4):

No, you cant.

There are only some nasty ways involving an alert message that has to be confirmed (works in most browsers).

In a real environment you should work with some server side logging based on account/ip and/or cookies.

In a test environment you could give the user a specific browser without that funcitonality. Firefox offers that in form of prism.

Answer (score 0):

Not unless you can give the user a browser which has had that functionality removed

Answer (score 0):

Not much control here, but did you try onUnload event of JavaScript.

```
<body onUnload='SaveCounterData();'>
```

This event is supposed to execute, when the page is being unloaded. Why/How (back button/refresh/closing window) it is being unloaded is not important here.